# java -version cannot be recognized, while PATH and JAVA_HOME are both set, windows 8

Tags: java, windows-8, path

I am using windows 8, and have tried to set JAVA_HOME as 

 `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05`

And PATH as

`%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

When I reopen the console, PATH still gives me:

`PATH = C:\Program Files .....; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin`

When I do `cd %JAVA_HOME%`, it guides me to the java directory:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05`

but when I open another new console and type `java -version` `javac` or 'jar', it reports error of "java/javac/jar" is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file....

So are there anything else that I didn't do? Isn't PATH clear enough to give the path to find "java"?

THanks!

Comment: Is there a space before `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin` in your `PATH`? Make sure that space is not there, because that is a problem.

Comment: What a Genius you are! Many many thanks! Indeed, there was a space before my directory.......

Answer (score 2):

The bin dir of your JAVA_HOME directory needs to be on your path.  Try

```
    echo %PATH%
```

to confirm whether or not this is the case.

Comment: It is on my PATH. This is the outcome: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin` then I punch in `java`. The out come is `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command......`

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` system environment variables.

See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).